# How to unit test a builder which uses a static singleton factory in its builder() method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, factory, builder

I am trying to unit test a Selenium page object API, and I have a bunch of builder classes that use a `static` singleton factory `class` to instantiate the desired object. I can't for the life of me figure out a way to unit test the `build()` method in the builder `class`. How do I mock 'object creation' for my builder?

```
public class LoadableBuilder<LoadableT extends ILoadable, BeanT extends ILoadableBean>
    implements ILoadableBuilder<LoadableT, BeanT> {

    /**
     * The ILoadableBean object that specifies all the necessary information to construct an instance of the
     * ILoadable that this LoadableBuilder builds
     */
    private final @Getter @Nonnull BeanT state;

    /**
     * The class that of the ILoadable that this LoadableBuilder builds
     */
    private @Getter @Nullable Class<LoadableT> componentClass;

    public AbstractLoadableBuilder(final BeanT state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public final @Nonnull LoadableBuilder setComponentClass(final Class<LoadableT> componentClass) {
        this.componentClass = componentClass;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public final @Nonnull LoadableBuilder setDriver(final WebDriver driver) {
        getState().setDriver(driver);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public final @Nonnull LoadableBuilder setLoadTimeoutInSeconds(final @Nonnegative int loadTimeoutInSeconds) {
        getState().setLoadTimeoutInSeconds(loadTimeoutInSeconds);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public @Nonnull LoadableT build() {
        return LoadableFactory.getInstance().create(getState(), componentClass);

    }
}
```

Here is the factory:

```
public class LoadableFactory {
    private static final class Loader {
        private static final LoadableFactory INSTANCE = new LoadableFactory();
    }

    private LoadableFactory() { }

    public static LoadableFactory getInstance() {
        return Loader.INSTANCE;
    }

    public final<BeanT extends ILoadableBean, LoadableT extends ILoadable> LoadableT create(final BeanT bean, final Class<LoadableT> componentClass) {
        final LoadableT component;

        try {
            final Constructor<LoadableT> ctor = ConstructorUtils.getMatchingAccessibleConstructor(componentClass, bean.getClass());
            component = ctor.newInstance(bean);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {                
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not instantiate an instance of " + componentClass + because it is abstract or an interface or for some other reason.");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not instantiate an instance of " + componentClass + " because the constructor threw an exception. Cause: " + e.getCause() +". " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw log.throwing(new IllegalArgumentException("Could not instantiate an instance of " + componentClass + " LoadableFactory does not have access to its class definition");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One way I've approached this problem in the past is to create another method which just holds the `getInstance()` call and then override it in the test (have your test extend your `LoadableBuilder` class). Your `LoadableBuilder` class just needs to be tested to make sure that it calls the `create()` method with the right arguments on whatever it gets back from the `LoadbableBuilder` it's been given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is best practice or not, but the way I've approached this kind of problem in the past is by moving the `getInstance()` call out to another, protected, method and then overriding it in my test class. You'll need to make your LoadableFactory implement an interface to mock out the `create()` call though:

```
protected ILoadableFactory getFactory(){
    return LoadableFactory.getInstance();
}
```

And then change your `LoadableBuilder` class to use this instead:

```
@Override
public @Nonnull LoadableT build() {
    return getFactory().create(getState(), componentClass);
}
```

Then, in your `LoadableBuilderTest` class:

```
public class LoadableBuilderTest extends LoadableBuilder {
    Mockery context = new Mockery();
    final LoadableFactory mockFactory = context.mock(ILoadableFactory.class); //This is the interface you'll need to make which LoadableFactory implements. It will need the create() method.

    @Override
    protected ILoadableFactory getFactory(){
        return mockFactory;
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCallCreateProperly(){
        context.checking(new Expectations(){{
            oneOf(mockFactory).create(arg1,arg2);
        }});
        //Do your stuff to test that create() was called.
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a better factory pattern that I could use that is more unit-testable which decouples it from the builders more effectively? I can change it since the API is under active development right now.

Comment: I'm not sure if its worth the decoupling, but you could make a service which provides an `ILoadableFactory` that you can then easily change in the future to provide various types of factories depending on configuration. But you'd still have to follow a similar pattern as this answer to unit test it.

Comment: So, I have followed your advice and written an interface for my factory, which my concrete class now implements. I am a little squicked out by having my builder use a protected method to access the factory. But, I like the testability. So, I am using your solution!

Comment: Thanks. The other method allows you a little bit more freedom in the retrieval of your builder, but I can understand the uneasiness in how it works. If you think about extending the class, you can now get a different factory in your subclasses, but leave everything else the same

Comment: Yeah, I realized that too after I thought about. I decided that this would be good for anyone who extends the builder, which is intended to be extended for all kinds of components. Thanks for the suggestion.